# plot a surface from pandas dataframe

Tags: python

[image]

Plot a surface from Pandas dataframe

then

```
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z, Y = np.meshgrid(z, y)

plt.contour(X, Y, Z)
plt.show()
```

it does not seem to work - any help how to make the Z work with the XY or if you have any recommendation to make such plot

Comment: Do you get an error message?

Comment: No error - just the surface does not look like a surface - but vertical lines

Comment: What are the shapes of your arrays?